# Where value is "undefined" when using Sequelize.not

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Using a simple sequelize query I keep getting error message "Invalid value { indefined: 0 }" when using the sequelize.not function as below

```
let total = await userDB.tblSMSSent.findOne({
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'id'), 'numMessages']],
        where: {
            user: userName,
            messageID: { [sequelize.not]: '0' }
        }, logging: false
    })
```

When I run the query without the 'MessageID: { [sequelize.not]: 0 }' filter it works fine (although with incorrect results).  How can I use the sequelize.not function correctly here?

In the database the messageId column is nchar(20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sequelize.Op.not`:

```js
    let total = await userDB.tblSMSSent.findOne({
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'id'), 'numMessages']],
        where: {
            user: userName,
            messageID: { [sequelize.Op.not]: '0' }
        }, logging: false
    })
```

Comment: That did it, after I imported Sequelize into the page rather than using my external connector.  Thank you.